# Create ATL dll project wizard creates two projects

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-c++, com, atl

After create new `ATL` dll project wizard compleated I got two projects - `myATL` (that was expected) and `myATLPS` (not expected).

Why it creates `myATLPS` project and what ending `PS` means? What does it used for?

Comment: PS means "proxy stub" and this creates a satellite project for building proxy/stub marshaller DLL for your type library and interfaces.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the ($Foo)PS project in my $Foo ATL solution for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9582733/what-is-the-foops-project-in-my-foo-atl-solution-for)